# When a DER format RSA private key is extracted from an encrypted PEM file, is it still encrypted?

Tags: rsa, public-key, openssl

Let's pretend we create a passphrase protected PEM file using `openssl`:

```
$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:password -out sample.pem 2048
```

And then extract the private key in DER format:

```
$ openssl rsa -in sample.pem -out sample.prv.der -outform DER
```

Is `sample.prv.der` still encrypted using the passphrase?

Comment: OpenSSL's 'legacy' privatekey formats, including PKCS1 for RSA, cannot be encrypted in DER form. If you want DER and encryption (PBE), use PKCS8. Or possibly PKCS12, although commandline can create PKCS12 only with both privatekey and cert/chain; doing privatekey alone requires writing a few lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will output the PKCS#1 compatible encoding of the private key, try this:

```
openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in sample.prv.der
```

it will output an ASN.1 sequence of:

- a version number (00);
- the modulus;
- the public exponent;
- the private exponent;
- the CRT parameters.

It did ask you for the password, right?